# How can I change the default Currency that Numbers pick up when creating a new file from a template?

Tags: numbers

I switched App Store region about a year ago, but Numbers is building new documents using the currency from my previous region by default. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not controlled by which App Store you use. Go to System Preferences > Language & Region, and change your region there.

Comment: I would have thought those 2 would be in sync. My bad